# Bootstrap floating columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve the thing below using Bootstrap but I'm stuck.

Here's what I want to do (plain CSS) : http://jsfiddle.net/n3rLx4n1/

Here's what I've done so far with bootstrap (I don't my comments start from the point where tags ends, I hope it's clear) : http://jsfiddle.net/rx4ptj2k/3/

Bootstrap code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 cover">
            <div>COVER</div>
            <div>MENU</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 info">
            <div>DETAILS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 tag">
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 yorum">COMMENTS</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Plain HTML + CSS

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="left-1">
            <div class="cover">COVER</div>
            <div class="menu">MENU</div>
        </div>
        <div class="left-2">
            <div class="info">DETAILS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="comments">COMMENTS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="tag">
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
            <div>TAG</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info {
        background: red;
    }

.tag {
        background: lightslategrey;
    }

.comment {
        background: cadetblue;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rx4ptj2k/4/

It should be fairly self explanatory (I've just nested divs to achieve the effect you want) but give me a shout if anything is unclear...

```
<div class="left col-sm-8 cover">
    <div class="cover col-sm-4">COVER</div>
    <div class="info col-sm-8">DETAILS</div>
    <div class="menu col-sm-12">MENU</div>
    <div class="comments col-sm-8">COMMENTS</div>
</div>
<div class="right col-sm-4 tag">
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
    <div>TAG</div>
</div>
```

If you don't mind the bootstrap padding, you can remove the first line of the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/rx4ptj2k/5/

Answer (score 1):

Just nest the divs. Bootstrap automatically adds padding, so I've removed it with the `.no-pad` class and added the background colors as inline styles for easier reference.

```
.no-pad {
    padding:0;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background:pink">
        <div class="col-xs-9 no-pad">
            <div class="col-xs-3 no-pad" style="background:red">
                COVER
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 no-pad" style="background:blue">
                DETAILS
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="background:orange">
                MENU
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9" style="background:purple">
                COMMENTS
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 no-pad" style="background:green">
            TAG<br>
            TAG<br>
            TAG<br>
            TAG<br>
            TAG<br>
            TAG<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/2okk4323/

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Joe Czucha answered it before, so I selected his answer but both answers are acceptable for me.